# Show large arrays as tables in Debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Is there a plugin for Visual Studio 2010 that shows arrays in a readable form (e.g. a table) during debug mode?

I tried "Array Visualizer", but it cannot completely show my int[60,95] array.

Something working for Visual C# would be enough for me.

Thank you!

Comment: if you have the time, you can write your own debugger visualizer, in fact, it's pretty easy and you can include any kind of data you like to see during debugging.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lior/archive/2009/05/31/creating-a-debugger-visualizer-for-visual-studio-c-tutorial.aspx